# Can inserts on ASP .net Dynamic Data be done on the same page with the list view?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

I would like to have users insert and edit information about entities on the same page in a similar fashion to google alerts: http://www.google.com/alerts/manage
Any advice on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible changing the routing in the method RegisterRoutes in Global.asax as indicated in the remarks section present in the same file.

Enabling this section:

```
routes.Add(new DynamicDataRoute("{table}/ListDetails.aspx") {
                  Action = PageAction.List,
               ViewName = "ListDetails",
               Model = DefaultModel
            });
```

instead of the already enabled:

```
routes.Add(new DynamicDataRoute("{table}/{action}.aspx")
            {
                Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(new { action =  List|Details|Edit|Insert" }), Model = DefaultModel
            });
```

It's also possible to enable custom routes for particular tables.